# How to say, "I will get him to get it done for them" in French using object pronouns?

Tags: pronoms, constructions-causatives

Do I use "se faire" for this as in "to get it done", like:

> Je vais se le faire pour eux?

or:

> *Je vais le faire pour le faire pour eux*

?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Neither *je vais se le faire pour eux* nor *je vais le faire pour le faire pour eux* would be used in French.

Here are some possible sentences:

> *Je vais le lui faire faire pour eux.*
>
> *Je vais faire en sorte qu'il le fasse pour eux.*
>
> *Je vais l'amener à le faire pour eux.*

*Amener* can also be replaced by *convaincre* in the last suggestion to better match the meaning of "to get someone to do something".

Comment: To me "get someone to do something" implies you have to find a agreement. What about "Je vais le convaincre de le faire pour eux"?

Comment: @vc74 Thanks, answer updated.